# Maven 3.2.2 does not prompt for password with -ep or -emp, but apache.org says it should

Tags: maven, git-bash, password-encryption

I'm trying to improve security around storing my maven repository password(s). This apache page:
(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) says:

> Prompting for Password
>
> In Maven before version 3.2.1 you have to give the password on command
>   line as argument (...). Starting with Maven 3.2.1 the password is an
>   optional argument which means if you omit the password you will be
>   prompted for it which prevents all the issues mentioned above.

Sounds great, I don't have to clear out bash history or vim cache. But it doesn't work as advertised!

I am using Maven 3.2.2 (see below) under the latest gitbash-for-windows under a Windows 2008 R2 server running Java 1.7 (I know, but I'm not an admin here).

What am I missing?

```
bb@MACHINE MINGW64 $ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T15:51:42+02:00)
Maven home: C:\tools\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\jre
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows servevr 2008 r2", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

bb@MACHINE MINGW64 $ mvn -ep
{}

bb@MACHINE MINGW64 $ mvn --encrypt-password
{}

bb@MACHINE MINGW64 $ mvn --encrypt-master-password
{}

bb@MACHINE MINGW64 $ mvn --emp
{}
```

It works fine if I do it the oldfashioned way:

```
bb@MACHINE MINGW64 $ mvn --encrypt-master-password myPwd
{pohBRxk/rXUHL/TT9wgt/sUvny5ssiCWsij1pgTpU7Q=}
```

Comment: Why using an old version of Maven?

Comment: Because it's apparently the default in this environment - not something I can help; there are some people who are afraid of upgrades. Anyway, 3.2.2 works for everything we use it for at the moment and it should still be new enough (see the link) to prompt me for a password.

Comment: Yeah, under Git CMD and cmd.exe it works... they need to look closer to impl for MINGW64

Comment: This question is 1.5 years old, and still applies.  I'm using maven 3.5.2 with the same issue.  When run in cygwin, the mvn -ep command does NOT prompt for a password.  It simply encrypts an empty string.  Is there a cygwin setting that we might be missng?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is a result of Java not recognizing Cyqwin as a console. Calls to **System.Console()** result in null.

Maven's behavior is to encrypt nothing when it cannot get a reference to the console.

```java
if ( cliRequest.commandLine.hasOption( CLIManager.ENCRYPT_MASTER_PASSWORD ) )
    {
        String passwd = cliRequest.commandLine.getOptionValue( CLIManager.ENCRYPT_MASTER_PASSWORD );
        System.out.println("["+passwd+"]");
        if ( passwd == null || passwd.isEmpty() || passwd.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
        {
            try {
            Console cons = System.console();
            char[] password = ( cons == null ) ? null : cons.readPassword( "Master password: " );
            if ( password != null )
            {
                // Cipher uses Strings
                passwd = String.copyValueOf( password );

                // Sun/Oracle advises to empty the char array
                java.util.Arrays.fill( password, ' ' );
            }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }

        DefaultPlexusCipher cipher = new DefaultPlexusCipher();

        System.out.println(
            cipher.encryptAndDecorate( passwd, DefaultSecDispatcher.SYSTEM_PROPERTY_SEC_LOCATION ) );

        throw new ExitException( 0 );
    }
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233846/java-console-in-cygwin) for why Cygwin does not work with **System.Console()**.

Your only option is to use **CMD**.