# java console in cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

On cygwin `java.lang.System.console()` returns null, crashing programs that call `readPassword` and such.

Is there some trick to make it work, short of changing the program to read from `stdin`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers it quite well:

https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/56

https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/244

> The problem is common to all Cygwin terminals using pseudo terminal
>   (pty)  devices, which Cygwin implements using Windows pipes. The
>   underlying reason is  that Windows doesn't have an interface that
>   would allow to emulate a console.  See issue 56 for details.

Comment: The last comment from mintty on the first issue is “Cygwin 3.1.0 has been released with ConPTY support.”, so maybe there is hope?